# SKNode subclass generates error: cannot invoke initializer for type "X" with no arguments

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

SKNodes can get initialized with an empty initializer, e.g., `let node = SKNode()`. Subclassing `SKNode`, however, breaks this functionality. After subclassing `SKNode`, Xcode generates this error when attempting to use the empty initializer on the subclass:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type "X" with no arguments
```

Assuming `SKNodeSubclass` is a subclass of `SKNode`, the line `let node = SKNodeSubclass()` generates this error.

> Is it possible to subclass from SKNode and also use an empty
>   initializer like with SKNode?

```
class StatusScreen: SKNode {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    init(gridWidth: CGFloat, deviceHeight: CGFloat) {
        super.init()

        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look at [The Swift Programming Language: Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html), under *Automatic Initializer Inheritance*, one of the rules for automatically inheriting a superclass's designated initialisers is:

> If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it
>   automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initialisers.

This assumes you provide default values for any new properties you introduce.

Since you're defining the designated initialiser `init(gridWidth: CGFloat, deviceHeight: CGFloat)` your subclass doesn't inherit `init()` from `SKNode`. Therefore, to be able to use `StatusScreen()` you need to override `init()` in your `StatusScreen` class:

```
class StatusScreen: SKNode {
    // ...

    override init() {
        super.init()

        // Do other stuff...
    }
}
```

Now you can use:

```
let node1 = StatusScreen()
let node2 = StatusScreen(gridWidth: 100, deviceHeight: 100)
```

Hope that helps!